# Pytorch - How do I concat imbalanced datasets in a way that the dataloader samples an equal number of sample from every dataset?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

Let's say I have datasets A and B.

A has 200 items and B has 100 items.

Pytorch has dataset.concat to create a new dataset with the new samples. E.g.:

```
C = torch.utils.data.concat([A, B])
```

How can I create a dataloader for C in the way that, for every epoch, it samples 200 items, 100 random items from A and the 100 items from B?